# call function not working with cd command

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to execute some shell commands using python :

The command is `cd /home/n1603031f/Desktop/parsec/wd/`

It works fine through the shell, but when executed through python it does not work :

```
path_to_wd = "/home/n1603031f/Desktop/parsec/wd/"
call(["cd",path_to_wd])
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

I need this command to work as the original command I want to execute is :

```
cd ./parsec/wd/ && tar -cf ../abcd.tar *
```

which works correctly only when you change directories to not create the top-level folders in the .tar file

Comment: `call(["cd", path_to_wd], shell=True)` works for me on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you had the right call to change directories it wouldn't accomplish what you want because each `subprocess.call` creates a separate process.

What you really need is the `cwd` argument to `subprocess.Popen` to say what directory you want to work in. Additionally you need to use `os.listdir` since the subprocess call won't go through a shell to expand the `*` glob. This is the right way to do what you're trying to do:

```
d = './parsec/wd'
subprocess.Popen(['tar', '-cf', '../abcd.tar'] + os.listdir(d), cwd=d).wait()
```

However, `os.listdir` will list hidden files as well, if you want to you can filter them out beforehand:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(d) if not f.startswith('.')]
```

If you *really* need to (and you don't,) you can use `shell=True` to get this to work with `*`. Though unless you're working with trusted input `shell=True` is widely considered a security vulnerability.

```
subprocess.Popen('tar -cf ../abcd.tar *', shell=True, cwd='./parsec/wd').wait()
```

If you need your python process to change it's current working directory, use

```
os.chdir('./parsec/wd')
```

Comment: `subprocess.Popen('tar -cf ../abcd.tar *', shell=True, cwd='./parsec/wd').wait()` is what I used and worked. Thank you for the time